# Copy Pivot Table as Picture with python

Tags: python, excel, pivot-table

How does it work to select a pivot table with Python and then copy it to a .png?

I am trying wb.Worksheets("Test").PivotTables(1) but it keeps throwing an error...

```
win32c = win32.constants
ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CopyPicture(Format=win32c.xlBitmap)
img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
image_path = 'C:/Prueba/test.png'
img.save(image_path)
excel.Quit()
```

Error:

> AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object
> Library.PivotTable instance at 0x2569187443096>' object has no
> attribute 'CopyPicture'

Comment: You may need to use Excel automation for this. Open the workbook and copy the table.

Comment: Any example of such?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use Excel automation to copy a pivot table  to an image file.

For this code, I used a sample Excel file which can be found here:
https://www.timeatlas.com/wp-content/uploads/pivot_table_example.xlsx

Here is the code to copy the pivot table from the sample file:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import win32com.client as win32
from PIL import ImageGrab

ExcelFile = 'C:/tmp/pivot_table_example.xlsx'
SheetName = "Sheet2"  # sheet with pivot table
ImgFile = 'C:/tmp/test.png'

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True

excel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFile)
excel.Sheets(SheetName).Select()
excel.Sheets(SheetName).PivotTables(1).TableRange1.Select()  # select first pivot table
excel.Sheets(SheetName).PivotTables(1).TableRange1.Copy()

img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
img.save(ImgFile)
excel.Quit()
```